# What are good text editors with RTL (right-to-left) support?

Tags: ubuntu, editors, unicode, right-to-left

`gvim` doesn't seem to support it out of the box on my Ubuntu lucid.

Comment: gvim does support it with :set rightleft.  You should know this setting is per-window.  If you use split windows, you can have one Window with rightleft enabled and a second window on the same file/buffer with rightleft disabled.  This is supposed to help with mixed RLT/LTR text.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you mention Gvim specifically I assume that its the editor your prefer.  Gvim/`vim` does support right-to-left text.

Use the option `:set rl` or the long form `:set rightleft` to enable it.  You can add this to your `.vimrc` if you want to always use it.

`vim` will need to be compiled with the `+rightleft` option.  I'm not 100% sure if Ubuntu does this, but CentOS does.  To check I did `vim --version | grep +rightleft` since `vim` can display what options it was compiled with.

Comment: I just fired up vim on Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick and confirmed that the version of `gvim` packaged there was compiled with right to left support.

Comment: vim/gvim on Ubuntu does.  I haven't seen any modern distro that doesn't compile with that option on.

Comment: Quick followup - how do you set left to right again?

Comment: `:set norl` sets it back to left-to-right.

Answer (score 1):

[Yudit](http://www.yudit.org/) is an editor specifically designed to cope well with “exotic” language and language combinations. This includes advanced support for [bidirectional text](http://www.yudit.org/en/howto/bidi/). On the minus side, it's otherwise rather primitive for an editor.

Emacs's development branch (what is currently known as Emacs 24.0.50.x and will eventually be Emacs 24.1) [supports bidirectional text](http://www.m17n.org/emacs-bidi/). On Ubuntu, try the [emacs-snapshot](http://packages.ubuntu.com/emacs-snapshot) [Install emacs-snapshot http://bit.ly/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/emacs-snapshot) package (as this is a development snapshot, you may be better off recompiling a more recent version).

Answer (score 1):

Since starting to study Arabic and also having to process it in scripts, etc., I keep trying out new text editors as I encounter them. However, and I'm clearly very opinionated here, Gedit beats them all. Hands-down. With most text editors *something* isn't just quite right, but with Gedit everything just works the way you'd expect it to. One small gripe is the new auto-disappearing scrollbar, which of course covers the first one or two Arabic letters in line of text starting on the right. On the command line, I use vim alternating between `:set rl`/`:set norl` as described above.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that JetBrains Editors have good RTL support.

I personally use their [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

They can be run on various platforms.

Answer (score -2):

RTL support in Linux is actually pretty good. As far as I can tell, anything that could be considered a "good text editor" also has RTL support.

I would pick your favorite editor based on other criteria, then if it's not obvious ask how to enable RTL support. If your primary system language is set to a RTL region most things seem to default to it pretty well.